# Why does my laravel app request favicon.ico?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-artisan

I do not have favicon specified and like a week ago i uploaded to the dev server an empty laravel project it worked perfectly, but on my local machine i cant even php artisan serve tha very basic laravel app, the one with the welcome blade that you get when you start a new laravel project. i will attach screenshots with the terminal and the browser. But i tried searching and creating an favicon as so many people said and nothing changed.

[the terminal ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhWam.png)

[the browser ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSwWW.png)

Comment: What does `storage/logs/laravel.log` says?

Comment: The browser will always try to load `favicon.ico` unless you specify another Favicon URL in a meta tag. According to your screenshot, you already serve a favicon there (I see status 200 OK) - but even if you didn't, it wouldn't matter (you would just get a 404 Not Found which the browser would ignore and show the default tab icon). So, the error 500 that you see has nothing to do with that. Instead, look in your Laravel logs for the source of the error.

Comment: [2022-02-02 11:42:13] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Encryption\\MissingAppKeyException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at E:\\proiecte IM\\RoyalDiamondTools\
oyalgroupchemical\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:101)
[stacktrace]